# External list - Access denied by Business Data Connectivity - Cannot add permissions

Tags: external-list, bdc

I created an external list, and got the "Access denied by Business Data Connectivity" error. So I tried to fix it by adding permissions on BDC Service, according to google, this is exactly what I have to do, cf [here](http://mssharepointserver.blogspot.fr/2011/02/access-denied-by-business-data.html) for example. And I agree with the solution.

But when I try adding groups or users, it brings me an error :
(Sorry for my bad traduction)
French :

```
Un nom d’utilisateur fourni n’a pas été codé comme une revendication.
Nom du paramètre : aces
```

English :

```
Username given had not been coded as a revendication.
Parameter name : aces
```

If someone can correct that, would be helpful.

P.S : I created my external list with SharePoint Designer.

Comment: Make sure you have at least read permissions on the external system the external list is using. Also are you getting this error in designer when you create the list or when you or others are attempting to access it through the SharePoint UI?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I don't get this error is SPD when I created the list. After long researches, it seems that I cannot give any permissions to users, because my services accounts give some problems. It's not normal, I can't add any users or groups in the people picker that manage permissions on the BDC service. So i'm trying a fresh install by side, and look if it comes from my services account.